# setInterval is called too often

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a setInterval functions which calls another function to be executed an hour later, however sometime it executes even as little as 5 minutes into the cycle.
Here is the way I do it:

```
function doSomething() {
 interval = setInterval(clickButton, 3600000);
}
```

and then I simply call doSomething() on document.ready()

This seems to work with smaller times such as 5 seconds or 2 minutes, however when it is set to the amount of milliseconds for an hour, it is never called every hour, but instead it seems to be random.

How do I ensure that setInterval will call the method every hour?

EDIT:

As Jamiec pointed out, I did not provide enough information at first and I was careless not to look for solutions relating to background information I should have provided. It turns out that the fault was with RaspberryPI which seems not be incapable of handling setInterval times that I require.

Instead I added a counter for setInverval that now calls the method every 15 minutes.

Thank you for pointing it out and helping me to arrive at a (hopefully) solution.

Comment: The code you have should call `clickButton` every hour. There is no more to it than that.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with the code you showed.

Comment: js timers are not precise! (so it might be  1 hour and 20ms )

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ocyuz3og/ <-- i'll let you know how my test goes :D

Comment: I would not mind if it were at least an hour wait, but on average I get 20 calls within an hour

Comment: @BambiOurLord you're definitely doing something wrong. Please show us a [mcve] demonstrating the problem - the code in this question does not.

Comment: @Jamiec, that is all there really is to the code, the method timeInterval calls simply creates an alert. I cannot reproduce the error on my device, but once the program runs on RapsberryPI it calls the function way too early and too often than the 1 hour it is set to.
I'm sorry that what I have shown is of no help, but that is all I have. 
I have just restarted the program 10 minutes ago on the RaspberryPI and so far it seems to not have called anything.

Comment: You never mentioned raspberrypi until now - there are lots of bugreports/questions where people complain about long intervals not working properly on the pi. Idon't like pointing to google search results but [just look](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=raspberrypi+setInterval&rlz=1C1GGRV_enGB751GB751&oq=raspberrypi+setInterval&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.5692j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I apologize for failing to mention it earlier. Seems I am too foolish to even think of that myself. Sorry to have wasted your time and thank you for pointing it out :)